# jQuery split and regroup list by <i> into new lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, split

I try to split the following html list into multiple lists, grouped by the headline, which is just marked with a   inside the list. I don't have an influence on the html so I have to reformat it using jquery. The length of the list groups are variable.

```
<div id="scrollerFilter">
<ul id="theListFilter">
    <li class="selected">All</li>
    <li><i>Industrial filter</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
        <li>bla 3</li>
        .....
        <li>bla 6235</li>
    <li><i>Functional filter</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
    <li><i>Regional filter</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
        <li>bla 3</li>
        <li>bla 4</li>
        <li>bla 5</li>
        <li>bla 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need the jquery to split the list into multiple lists using  as Headline/Group identifier. Result should look like this:

```
<div id="scrollerFilter">
<ul id="theListFilter" class="column1">
    <li><i>Industrial</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
        <li>bla 3</li>
        .....
        <li>bla 6235</li>
</ul>
<ul id="theListFilter" class="column2">
    <li><i>Functional</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="theListFilter" class="column3">
    <li><i>Regional</i></li>
        <li>bla 1</li>
        <li>bla 2</li>
        <li>bla 3</li>
        <li>bla 4</li>
        <li>bla 5</li>
        <li>bla 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I allready found out how to split the list static by count and regroup it and than move it to another div and remove the old one, but this isn't a option because the list groups are variating and the reloaction to another div is not necessary.

```
var total = $("#scrollerFilter li").size();
var count = 4;
var column = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < total; i += count) {
column++;
$("#newDIV").append('<ul id="columns' + column + '"></ul>');
$("#columns" + column).html($("#scrollerFilter li").splice(0, count));
}
$("#scrollerFilter").remove();
```

So this jquery part is useless.
Thank you very much for helping me on this task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    var $ulelement;
    $('#theListFilter li').each(function(index){
        if($(this).children("i").length>0)
        { 
            $ulelement = $('<ul id="theListFilter'+index+'" class="column1"></ul>');
            $ulelement.appendTo('#scrollerFilter');
        }
       $(this).appendTo($ulelement);
       if($('#theListFilter').is(':last-child')) // remove first ul
          $('#theListFilter').remove();
    });
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8PmM/17/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution I searched for!

Answer (score 1):

Not optimised, but you could do something like this:

```
var $listContent = $('#theListFilter').detach();

$listContent.find('i').each(function() {
    $('<ul>').append( $(this).parent().nextUntil('li:has(i)').addBack() ).appendTo('#scrollerFilter');
});
```

`detach()` the `#theListFilter`, then find and loop each `i` within it, wrapping their parent `li`, and all sibling `li`'s up until the next `li` containing an `i` in an `ul`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u73PE/28/)

**edit**

A more optimised version of the above:

```
var $listContent = $('#theListFilter').detach(),
    newContent = [];

$listContent.find('i').each(function(i) {
    newContent[i] = $(this).parent().nextUntil('li:has(i)').addBack().wrapAll('<ul class="column' + (i+1) + '">').parent();
});

$('#scrollerFilter').append( newContent );
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u73PE/34/)

Answer (score 1):

As we can't use same `id` for multiple elements, I am using `theListFilter` as `class`

Try this:

```
var theListFilter = $('#theListFilter');
var theListFilterClone = theListFilter.clone();
var scrollerFilter = $('#scrollerFilter');
var column = 0;
var ul = $('<ul>');
theListFilter.remove('');
theListFilterClone.find('li').each(function(i, v) {
    li = $(v);
    if (li.html() === 'All') {
        return;
    }
    if (li.find('i').length) {
        li.find('i').html(li.find('i').html().replace(' filter', ''));
        if (i > 1) {
            column++;
            ul.addClass('theListFilter cloumn' + column);
            scrollerFilter.append(ul);
            ul = $('<ul>');
        }
    }
    ul.append(li);
});
column++;
ul.addClass('cloumn' + column);
scrollerFilter.append(ul);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6tfu/)

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
var markup = $('#scrollerFilter').html().split('<li><i>'),
    tmp;
for (var i = 0; i < markup.length; i++) {
    if (markup[i] != undefined)
        tmp += '<ul id="theListFilter" class="column' + (i + 1) + '">' + markup[i] + '</ul>';
}
$('#scrollerFilter').html(tmp)
```